# Die class in Java with external code

Tags: java, class

I have a section of code that someone else wrote, and I cannot figure out how to make the code work with it.
I'm supposed to make a single Die roll and display a number between 1 and 6 using:

```
    (int)(math.random()*6 + 1);
```

The code provided is this:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Ch3_PrExercise6

{
  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Die die1 = new Die();
    Die die2 = new Die();
    System.out.println("die1: " + die1.getRoll()):
    System.out.println("die2: " + die2.getRoll());
    System.out.println("After rolling, die1: " + die1.rollDie());
    System.out.println("After rolling, die2: " + die2.rollDie());
    System.out.println("After second roll, die1: " + die1.rollDie());
    System.out.println("After second roll, die2: " + die2.rollDie());
  }
}
```

So far, all I can come up with is:

```
public class Die
{
  //Sets initial value to 1
  public int startFace
  {
    startFace = 1;
  }
  //Roll the die
  public int rollDie
  {
    rollDie = (int)(math.random()*6 + 1);
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what the other program wants from me in the getRoll line. I understand that rollDie is called in the last four print commands.

I'm using Processing 2.20, If that's important.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what exactly it is you're asking.  I'm lost.

Comment: There's no return statement in the `rollDie()` method - instead of `rollDie =`, use `return`; this is how return values in Java are produced.  Also there's no need for a `startFace()` method in the above example.

Comment: My best guess is that `getRoll()` should return the 'current' face up value of the die (i.e. result of last roll or some standard value if not rolled yet). But that is just a guess based on my opinion and not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Try to understand problem you are working and then figure out solution.

Comment: Alright. I feel like I'm being attacked now. I realize that the code isn't done, and I'm working on it. I've gotten a few good suggestions so I think I'll try to get the rest on my own. Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that compiles? You're expecting rollDie to be a function, you can tell that because you have

```
 die1.rollDie()
```

Note the parentheses: a function call.

so make a function and have it return a value:

```
public int rollDie()
{
    int rollResult = (int)(math.random()*6 + 1);
    return rollResult
}
```

Comment: I'm still working on figuring out everything that the other code wants while I work on the code. But yes, you are correct. It doesn't compile at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would upvote djna and accept his answer.  To elaborate, I think this is all you need:

```
public class Die
{
  private int face = 1;

  // Get current value
  public int getRoll ()  {
    return face;
  }

  //Roll the die, return new value
  public int rollDie ()  {
    face = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
    return face;
  }

}
```

Comment: The assignment also seems to imply that dice remember their last roll and support a `getRoll` call.